# How to iterate over an array with HAML?

Tags: ruby, iteration

I have this in a HAML layout (layout.haml)

```
- @fonts.each do |font|
  %link{:href=>"//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family={font}",:rel=>"stylesheet",:type=>"text/css"}
```

And I have this in the HAML template index.html.haml

```
- @fonts = ['Lato:400,300,100','Droid+Serif:700,400'];
```

When I compile, I get this:

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family={font}' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family={font}' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Posted and answered 8 years ago ... And it helped me today ! Thank you for that :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot the hash symbol.

```
- @fonts.each do |font|
  %link{:href=>"//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=#{font}",:rel=>"stylesheet",:type=>"text/css"}
                                                  ^ here
```

Comment: To clarify, the single fix is at `family=#{font}` where-as you had `family={font}` which is not correct string interpolation.

Comment: Geze, thanks!  I said I was a Newbie to Ruby, and I meant it!