# Haml produces "{}" text on webpage

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, web, haml

I am trying to convert from application.html.erb to application.haml and I get one small annoying  problem being "{}" in top left corner.

[image: problem]

My code looks like this:

```
  %body
    = render 'shared/header'
    .container
      = flash.each do |message_type, message|
        .alert{class: "alert-#{message_type}"}= message
        -# = content_tag :div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}"
      = yield
      = render 'shared/footer'
```

Commented out line is a second way to create div, but it produces same error.

HTML before conversion looked like this:

```
  <body>
    <%= render 'shared/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
          <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'shared/footer' %>
    </div>
  </body>
```

What's wrong with that? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're outputting the return value of your `flash.each` loop

```
= flash.each do |message_type, message|
```

don't write in haml, but after a quick google it looks like maybe use

```
- flash.each do |message_type, message|
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you. Could you guide me what did you search for? I would be more then happy to read that as well, as it's quite hard to find proper HAML documentation and examples.

Comment: I just googled "looping through array in haml" and ended up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119053/how-to-iterate-over-an-array-with-haml). Wasn't a full blown haml guide or anything